# performance of django translation

Tags: django

I'm currently making a site where i want to implement multi-language version. which actually i don't need but i want to do it just in case.

So will using django translation mechanism reduce performance and for how much?
Especially i want to hear people how have tested performance of django translation on real servers.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't talk from experience about performance on real servers, but here are a few hints:

Django loads the gettext translations for a language into memory as soon as the language is activated (e.g. manually with `django.utils.translation.activate("de")`). After the MO file is loaded, all further lookups are purely CPU-bound (memory lookup), so the performance hit shouldn't matter at all.

If I understand your question correctly, you only want to place translatable strings into the site so that you *could* translate them when necessary. In that case, just use `ugettext`, `{% trans %}` etc. like you would do for a fully-translated site, but set `USE_I18N = False`. That way, Django replaces its gettext functionality with dummy functions that will just return the original string. The overhead will be close to zero. If you want to add a second language, just activate i18n and don't forget to compile the translations to MO files.